How can I configure my search component to show me assets with Status (M.Final.LifeCycle.Status) archived and approved?
I recently created an asset page, and I need to configure my search component so that it shows me assets with Status (M.Final.LifeCycle.Status) archived and approved, I have been configuring my filters and tried using both And & Or options, but when I enter the filters for both statuses the page does not show any asset at all.
I am just wondering if this is possible or not and if it is, I would appreciate it if someone could please let me know the right way to do it.
I have attached a screenshot so you can better understand what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance.
Alba

So in Content Hub, composite conditions in filters work such that when you apply a composite, like 'AND' in your case, every filter falls under this 'AND' condition, including nested ones  —see the screenshot.

All you need to do is take the archived condition and place it under the approved condition, then change the nested composite condition from 'AND' to 'OR'.

You can configure search component to retrieve Assets with Final Lifecycle status as Approved as well as Archived by adding them under the composite OR condition as below.

Note: Both these states Approved as well as Archived should be under  composite OR condition.
Each state Approved or Archived under Composite tab can be configured as shown below.

Using above way, search component can be configured to show Assets that are in Approved or Archived state. Let me know in case you have any doubts.
Hope this helps!!!
